# Как поменять разрешение экрана входа в систему в Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Всем привет! Можете пожалуйста сказать как сделать экран входа в систему нормального разрешения. Все перерыл, так и не нашел четкого ответа. В качестве DM стоит gdm3. Я новичок в ubuntu, поэтому прошу более-менее лояльного ответа

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте подробности. Какое разрешение сейчас, какое хочется, какие поддерживает видокарта, какие поддерживает монитор, модель видеокарты. Версия Ubuntu, какая графическая подсистема - X11 или Wayland.

Comment: Не знаю какое у экрана входа, но на рабочем столе 1920x1080, хотелось бы такое же и у экрана входа. Видеокарта и монитор поддерживают 1920 на 1080, 1600 и 1200 и тд, все перечислять я думаю не нужно, модель видеокарты GT 730,  графическая подсистема X11